# In App Purchase Notification When User Make Purchases

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes-store

I just implemented In App Purchase for my app and got approved by Apple. However, when my friends successfully made purchases in my app, I don't receive any notifications from Apple and there is nothing showing in my itunes connect sales and IAP sections. Is it normal or should I contact App Store support?